# 'Compiled with different version` error when compiling library

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, skins

I downloaded the new beta version of [AlphaSkins Lite](http://www.alphaskins.com/dwnld.php) (7.44). I uninstalled the older version that i had problems with... I opened the "acntD7_R.dpk" and it compiled. Then I opened "acntD7.dpk" and got a compile error:

```
[Fatal Error] acntD7.dpk(47): Unit sInternalSkins was compiled with a different version  of sButton.TsButton
```

I tried to erase the BPL files manually and tried again but got the same error message again.

Please what i am doing wrong?

Comment: are you tried deleting the dcu files of the older version as well?

Comment: This is most likely a path issue... Make sure you've deleted all the .dcus from the old version and you've updated the library and search paths (from both the Tools->Options and Project->Options menu items - don't have D7 installed any longer, so I don't have the exact menu item names) to point to the new version for all of the AlphaControls.

Comment: I solve it... this is what i do.... I erase the dcp files of alphalite and works... thank you for help...

Comment: @Ken @RRUZ please create an answer that azrael11 can accept.

Comment: @Smasher would just be better to delete the Q

Comment: This might well be a problem that other might stumble upon (with any library). Now I don't know if there already is a duplicate but if not the question is definitely useful to others IMHO.

Comment: @Smasher maybe, but why would anyone's search lead to this question?

Comment: @David, you are right I edited the title to make it more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Search your computer for a file named "sInternalSkins.pas". Be sure, the path of this file is included as a path in your delphi library pathes. If not, include this path in delphi options. If you do not have the *.pas, you have to find the dcu-File that was compiled with your delphi compiler version. Maybe you have the correct dcu but your search-path points to a wrong path with the wrong version of the dcu. Different versions of DCU's are often stored in different directories, one for each delphi version, if source is not part of the component. (I personally never use components without source...)
2. If you have the *.pas: search your computer for all files named "sInternalSkins.dcu" and delete them all.
3. Rebuild your package acntD7.dpk

Comment: And if you need to search files, you should try "`Everything`"  (http://www.voidtools.com/). It's pretty handy to find units on your harddrive. and it's free..

Answer (score 0):

Additionally check compiler options of YOUR project. Some AlphaSkins files go with source code, another - as DCU only. Source code may be rebuilt, but DCUs require standard compiler options, i.e. (particulary) "Huge strings" and "Record alignment to 8".